# Calling Python method with two defined parameters, but passing only one variable

Tags: python, methods, syntax, parameters

I'm struggling to understand following code snippet:

```
@metric
def area(prev, nxt):
    """Area of a polygon with points in clockwise order."""
    return area_piece(prev, nxt) / 2

def centroid(points):
    a = area(points)
    return [center_x_helper(points)/a, center_y_helper(points)/a]

@metric
def center_x_helper(prev, nxt):
    return (prev[0] + nxt[0]) * area_piece(prev, nxt) / 6

@metric
def center_y_helper(prev, nxt):
    return (prev[1] + nxt[1]) * area_piece(prev, nxt) / 6

def area_piece(prev, nxt):
    return nxt[0] * prev[1] - prev[0] * nxt[1]
```

The full code is located [here](https://github.com/benjaminjkraft/gerrymandering/blob/master/compactness.py).

I assume that `points` is some kind of 2D array/list, where each item contains a pair of X- and Y-coordinates. Somehow though, `points` is passed to `area(prev, nxt)` to perform the calculations on each pair of coordinates.

When I try one of following

`centroid([[150, 200], [0, 300], [0, 400], [3, 1]])`

`centroid([150, 200, 0, 300, 0, 400, 3, 1])`

I get this error:

`TypeError: area() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nxt'`

Am I missing something here or is this code simply not runnable this way?

Comment: The arrays you used, what kind were they. Length shape etc..?

Comment: @ljetibo exemplary method calls added with last edit

Comment: @ljetibo so `@metric` is defined by the function `def metric(function)` and is executed each time before the "annotated" (decorated?) function itself is executed? and the annotated function then receives the return-value of `metric(function)` as parameter(s)?

Comment: That's usually how decorators work, they take in a function, do something and then call the function. They return a function so that when you start the program the function you decorated gets "replaced" with this new function of the same name but that also does something before the original function is called. [see this](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

Comment: Well, that's something I did not know before. Now I think, I will be able to understand the entire code. If you write an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having, I believe, is not sending the list in correct format.

I don't know in the full code where the `shape` comes from. What happens when `centroid` is called is that `area` is called. But before area is actually executed decorator `metric` is called (line 77 in the original code). `metric` then re-arranges the input lists (line 85, 86) called `points` and then calls the original function `area` on those re-arranged lists.

Except metric doesn't act on "points" and works with something called `shape` the definition of which I can't find but has to be somewhere in the original code. There's a lot of methods `shape` has that aren't a part of list, for example `.points`, `.parts`, `.tolist` etc...

For `area` you need to send two "points" which seem to be just lists of length 2 as in: `area([1,2], [4,5])`. I base this on his docstring text `function should take two points (each lists of length 2) and return some....`

But because of the decorator you can also call the function `area` with `shape`. This is because before anything is done, `metric` is called and `shape` is re-arranged so that `area` is called on just two "points". So what you need to do is find what `shape` is and then call `centroid` with that. I'm not willing to dig deeper to find what exactly `shape` is or how to get the code working properly, so if anyone else pulls the code and tests it you need to accept his answer.

Additionally, the way you can think about how decorators usually is that they take in a function, maybe do something before, then call the function, and then maybe do something after it. They return a function so that when you start the program the function you decorated gets "replaced" with this new function of the same name but that also maybe does something else/different. See [this](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) for more on decorators.

For posterity - this was in the comments and was edited a bit to fit the form of an answer after which comments were deleted. Also I like points.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `area(prev, nxt)` takes two arguments, however in your `centroid(points)` function, you assign a variable `a` to be the result of of your `area(prev, nxt)` function, but you're only passing it one argument, namely `points`.

```
def centroid(points):
    a = area(points, secondArgumentNeedsToGoHere)
```

Comment: You're not completely correct as the function `area` has a decorator that will call it with two arguments.